# Bitmask'ed Int to Enum[] or Int[]? c#

Tags: c#, bitmask

I have an enum that looks like this:

```
enum foo{
a=0,
b=1,
c=2,
d=4
}
```

Building the flag / bitmask is fine, but is it possible to do something like

```
int i = 3;
var bar =  Enum.Split(foo,i);
```

Resulting in something like

```
bar = foo[]{a, b,c};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Split<T>(int value) {
  foreach (object cur in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))) {
    var number = (int)(object)(T)cur;
    if (0 != (number & value)) {
      yield return (T)cur;
    }
  }
}
```

With this you can now write

```
int i = 3;
IEnumerable<foo> e = Split<foo>(i);
```

Note: This only works on `enum` values which derive from `int` (the default setting).  It's also not entirely type safe as `T` can't be constrained to only `enum` values (nothing to do about that though)

Comment: Like it Jared, Im suprised there isnt an inbuilt operator that solves this out the box.

Comment: Why we can not add `where T : Enum` ?

Comment: @Vash C# doesn't allow generic parameters to be constrained to `enum` values.

Comment: @JaredPar, true but we operate with a class there not value, so this should be possible, but in this example problematic for me `(int)(T)`. Dose this raise compilation error ?

Comment: @Vash added the missing `object` cast.

Comment: [Yoda conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307) make me nervous.

Comment: @Snowbear why? Nervous doesn't seem to make sense because this is completely safe and hence what's to be nervous about?  I could understand "annoyed", "bothered" because you don't like the style but nervous doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: @JaredPar I've tried this out, and it works beautifully. Could you explain why it works for enums that _don't_ have the `Flags` attribute applied to them?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) on the enum and get lots of the functionality for free (no need to work at the bit level).

MSDN describes the attribute as:

> Indicates that an enumeration can be treated as a bit field; that is, a set of flags.

Comment: And how does that Split a combined value into an array?

Comment: @Henk - It doesn't, however, using them may obviate the reasons for wanting to split the combined value.

Answer (score 2):

The `[FlagsAttribute]` allows you to extract all of the valid values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
TEnum[] EnumSplit<TEnum>(int mask)
{
    List<TEnum> values = new List<TEnum>();
    foreach(int enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        if(mask & enumValue == enumValue)
            values.Add((TEnum)enumValue);
    }
    return values.ToArray();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var bar = EnumSplit<foo>(i);
```

Preferably, you want to change it to return `IEnumerable<TEnum>` instead of `TEnum[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a method which pulls the values from the `Enum` you pass:

```
public static T[] EnumSplit<T>(int value) where T : struct
{
    // Simplified as Enum.GetValues will complain if T is not an enum
    // However, you should add a check to make sure T implements FlagAttribute
    return (from vv in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
            where ((int)vv & value) != 0
            select (T)vv).ToArray();;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var flags = Enum.GetValues(typeof (/* YourEnumType */))
                  .Cast</* YourEnumType */>()
                  .Select(v => enumValue.HasFlag(v))
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't believe that will compile as C# has no way of knowing that `T` implements `HasFlag`.